# Chose different symbols to display in a different plots

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I have the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{My figure}
\label{evolQAS}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                      group name=myplot,
                      group size= 2 by 1},height=5cm,width=6.4cm]
        \nextgroupplot[title=MAP,xlabel={$\lambda$ values},ylabel={Performance evolution }, label=mapC]
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=1] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot1}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=2] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot2}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=3] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot3}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=4] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot4}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=5] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot5}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=6] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot6}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=7] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot7}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=8] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot8}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=9] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot9}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=10] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot10}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=11] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot11}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=12] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot12}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=13] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot13}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=14] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot14}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=15] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot15}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=16] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot16}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=17] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot17}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=18] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot18}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=19] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot19}
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=20] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_map_cB};\label{plots:plot20}
        \nextgroupplot[title=$P@5$,xlabel={$\lambda$ values}]
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=1] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=2] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=3] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=4] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=5] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=6] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=7] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=8] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=9] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=10] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=11] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=12] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=13] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=14] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=15] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=16] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=17] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=18] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=19] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
  \addplot table [x=lmda,y=20] {inserted/BM25/ap_alpha_p5_cB};
    \end{groupplot}
    \path (myplot c1r1.outer north west)% plot in column 1 row 1
          -- node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {}% label midway
          (myplot c1r1.outer south west)% plot in column 1 row 4
    ;
% legend
\path (myplot c1r1.north west|-current bounding box.north)--
      coordinate(legendpos)
      (myplot c2r1.north east|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=south,
    draw,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    draw
  ]at([yshift=0.5ex]legendpos)
  {
    \ref{plots:plot1}& 1&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot2}& 2&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot3}& 3&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot4}& 4&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot5}& 5&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot6}& 6\\
    \ref{plots:plot7}& 7&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot8}& 8&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot9}& 9&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot10}& 10&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot11}& 11&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot12}& 12\\
    \ref{plots:plot13}& 13&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot14}& 14&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot15}& 15&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot16}& 16&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot17}& 17&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot18}& 18\\
    \ref{plots:plot19}& 19&[5pt]
    \ref{plots:plot20}& 20\\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
```

The resulting figure is :
[image: My figure]

But as you can see, there are some symbols that are used in different plots, what makes my figure ambiguous (like 2 and 12, 3 and 13 ...). How can I cope with this? I want also adjust the scalar (or scale) of the curve to separate the different plots because they stacked.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, welcome. It's too late in the evening right now to make a proper answer, but you could choose a different `cycle list` for the second `groupplot`. See section 4.7.7 *Cycle lists -- Options Controlling Line Styles* in the `pgfplots` manual (for version 1.15, might be a different section in the manual for other versions) for a description of the ones that are available by default, as well as instructions for making your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Torbjørn already mentioned in the comment below the question, you need to change the `cycle list` to solve your problem and there are various possibilities to do so. Here I present only one way to do so using two of the predefined `cycle list`s.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend entries={1,...,20},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend columns=10,
        transpose legend=true,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % adjust that part to get your desired result
        % (this is a very simple example to not get repeating styles)
        cycle multiindex* list={
            color       \nextlist
            mark list*  \nextlist
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,...,20} {
            \addplot coordinates { (0,\i) (1,\i) };
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, this is verry helpfull for me. Have a good day :)

Comment: I used it and I got results that I was looking for;: